# Angular overlaypanel it is staying everytime open

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have created an Angular component like p-overlaypanel but it is staying open for every item I click, I want if I click another overlay panel the last clicked should be hidden, I wan'T only one to be clicked and show not everyone of them
Below you can find code in stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrsyt6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Here is the code

```
<div class="dropdown">

  <div  class="body">
    <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="active" class="popup">
    <ng-content select="[popup]"></ng-content>
  </div>

</div>
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

export class OverlaypanelComponent implements OnInit {

  active = false;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) clickedOutside($event) {
    this.active = false;
  }

  toggle($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.active = !this.active;
  }

  close() {
    this.active = false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you will have to have the child component (panel) somehow communicate to the parent that it has opened, and it will be the parent's responsibility to close the other panels. To that end, the `active` property should also be an Input binding. This means the addition of at least three things one way or the other: an Input binding to determine if the panel is active, an Input binding to identify the panel, and an Output binding to signal that the panel is being shown:

```
@Input() active = false;
@Output() activeChanged = new EventEmitter();
@Input() index;

toggle($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  this.active = !this.active;
  if (this.active) {
    this.activeChanged.emit(this.index);
  }
}
```

Now your parent component will have to bind to these properties and also respond to the Output to change the bindings of the other panels. This should be pretty easy to do with an array or some iterative data structure that you can use to contain the panels.

```
  panels = new Array(4).fill({ active: false });

  closeOtherPopups(index) {
    this.panels = this.panels.map((panel, idx) => (
      { active: idx === index }
    ));
  }
```

See this in action here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u96ssk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: This is working but how to define not dynamically the overlays because the overlay are connected with another array and for example there are 40 list of array and have to be 40 overlay panels

Comment: You can still have an array that controls the active state of the panels and link to the list by index or something

Comment: And how can I do this ?

Comment: I think that may merit a separate question. Your current question doesn't have enough information to determine where you're unclear about that.

Comment: I will try to reproduce another stackblitz and put it here.

Comment: I have added the stackblitz in the question I have edited the question

Comment: I don't understand your issue. You can use your `items` array in pretty much the same way that I used `panels`; just copy all of the item properties when you recreate the array `return { ...item, active: activeId === item.id }`

Comment: Can you write the code because I have tried but it is not working